# Venn diagram showing various types of events in probability theory

Tags: probability

[image: Venn Diagram Events]

Is this an appropriate Venn diagram for different types of events classified as independent/dependent, mutually exclusive/non-mutually exclusive?

Comment: It takes many assumptions, some knowledge, and a bit of creativity to make sense of this diagram.  I cannot find an interpretation that makes it correct, but I haven't tried very hard ;-).  Since I have some understanding of the concepts, that leads me to suspect this approach might not be suitable for any of its intended audiences.  Have you considered drawing *separate* diagrams for different concepts?

Comment: Thanks you. I will start from scratch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say no, this is not appropriate.

To me it seems the diagram is showing that the space of all collections of events can be divided into either independent or dependent events and that these two categories include all possible collections of events. That's correct.

It also shows that some events can either be defined as non-mutually exclusive or mutually exclusive. The problem is that it looks like there are events which are neither non-mutually exclusive nor mutually exclusive. This is not correct. All collections of events are either non-mutually exclusive or mutually exclusive. So, the non-mutually exclusive box should expand to include all of the space in the independent events section and both the non-mutually exclusive and mutually exclusives boxes should expand to fill all the space in the dependent events section.

Comment: As Bertrand Russell brilliantly showed over a century ago, there is no such thing as "the space of all collections of events."  If we were to interpret Venn diagrams more metaphorically and not as about relations among *sets,* this would not be an objection.  The real objection is that it isn't clear how either the OP or you are interpreting this diagram.  How one reads it seems to be rather a subjective matter.